# Dynamically Populate JQUERY Mobile Multi-Page Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

JQUERY Mobile Beginner Question:  I have two pages in my simple multi-page JQUERY Mobile 'App'.  When the user navigates to PAGE2, I want to do an AJAX call to get a JSON object containing a list of people + DB ID pairs.  I want to present the list of people as buttons on PAGE2.

Code Snippet:

```
<div id="PAGE2" data-role="page">
  <div class="ui-content">
     // I want buttons to appear sequentially here
  </div>
</div>
```

PAGE2 is my "placeholder" to populate with:

```
<input type="button" id="id1" name="id1" value="Bob Smith"/>
<input type="button" id="id2" name="id2" value="Jane Doe"/>
<input type="button" id="id3" name="id3" value="Kayla Kaye"/>
```

I'd also need to add a 'click' event handler in the script to react to the buttons.  The reaction will be the same for all buttons (dynamically populate a PAGE3 with people detail, but I think I can figure that out if I see how PAGE2 population is correctly handled).  What is the proper way to go about dynamically "creating" PAGE2 using the skeleton in place?

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is allowed:

```
    var elements = { id1:'Bob Smith', id2:'Jane Doe', id3:'Kayla Kaye'};
    $.each( elements, function( key, value ) {
        $("#PAGE2 .ui-content").append('<input type="button" id="' + key + '" name=" + key " value " + value +'"/>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#PAGE2').on('pagebeforeshow', function(){

    var people = [
      { name:'Bob Smith', age:'56', place:'London'},
      { name:'John', age:'65', place:'USA'},
    ];

  var btns;

   $.each(people,function(indx,ppl){

      btns = btns + '<input type="button"  name="id1" value="' +  ppl.name +'"/>';

    });

   $('#content_div').html(btns);

});
```

set id to div content to content_div

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3t4cqtya/)**

With your 3 pages setup like this (I have added container divs for the buttons and details):

```
<div data-role="page" id="PAGE1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>PAGE 1</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#PAGE2" class="ui-btn">Go to page 2</a>
    </div> 
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="PAGE2">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>PAGE 2</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="thePeople"></div>
    </div> 
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="PAGE3">
     <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-back">Back </a>
        <h1>PAGE 3</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="theDetails"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

You can use the pagecontainer widget's beforeshow event to make your ajax call:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow

In my example, I am checking where you are coming from and where you are going to. So coming from PAGE1 to PAGE2, I make the AJAX call and create the buttons. But if returning from PAGE3 to PAGE2, I just leave the already created buttons alone.  Ater adding the buttons to the page, make sure and call **[.enhanceWithin()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** on the container so that jQM enhances the buttons.

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    var prevID = ui.prevPage.prop("id");
    var newID = ui.toPage.prop("id");

    if (prevID == "PAGE1" && newID == "PAGE2") {
        //we have come from page 1 to page 2, so make AJAX call and populate page 2
         var data = [
              { "id": "id1", "name":'Bob Smith'},
              { "id": "id2", "name":'Jane Doe'},
              { "id": "id3", "name":'Kayla Kaye'},
        ];

        var buttons = '';
        $.each(data, function(indx){
            buttons += '<input type="button" name="' + this.id + '" value="' +  this.name +'"/>';
        });
        $("#thePeople").empty().append(buttons).enhanceWithin();  
    }
});
```

Finally, when PAGE2 is created, I use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to create a click event for any buttons that might be added (with event delegation, the buttons don't have to exist at the time the event is bound). In the event, get the id/name for the button that is clicked, get the details (Another AJAX call?), populate PAGE3, and then navigate to PAGE3 using the pagecontainer widget change method:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#PAGE2", function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#thePeople input[type="button"]', function(e){
        var personid = $(this).prop("id");
        var name = $(this).val();
        $("#theDetails").text('Details for ' + name);
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#PAGE3", { transition: "slide" });
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3t4cqtya/)**